# Why the complete JSON is not being sent to mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, json, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I have a functionality on a webpage, that uploads an excel file to Node and parse it to JSON, then pass the data to mongodb. It only sends one document to mongodb, each document is organized inside of an array and iterate through each one using a for loop, so the only one that is being sent is the first document. I tried also to use the model.create(docs) function which sends each document to the database but is the same issue. This is the code(the model.create(docs) is inside the //////////////):

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
var exceltojson;
upload(req, res, function(err){
    if (err) {
        res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err})
        return;
    }
    if(!req.file){
        res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:"No file passed"});
        return;
    }

    if(req.file.originalname.split('.')[req.file.originalname.split('.').length-1] === 'xlsx'){
        exceltojson = xlsxtojson;
    } else {
        exceltojson = xlstojson;
    }
    try {
        exceltojson({
            input: req.file.path,
            output: "./outPutJSON/output.json",
            lowerCaseHeaders: true
        }, function(err, result){
            if(err){
                return res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:err, data: null});
            }
            res.json({datos:"Los datos fueron agregados exitosamente"});
            //res.json({error_code:0, err_desc:null, data: result});

            let resultDos = fs.readFile("./outPutJSON/output.json", 'utf8', (err, fileContents) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err)
                  return;
                }
                try {
                  const data = JSON.parse(fileContents)
                  console.log(data.length);

                  //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                  model.create(data, function (err) {
                      if(err){
                          console.log(err);
                      }
                  });

                  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                  //for(var cantidad = 0; cantidad < data.length;cantidad++{
                    //let documento = data[cantidad];
                    //let mod = new model(documento);
                    //console.log(documento);
                   // mod.save(function(err){
                    //    if(err){
                        //    console.log(err);
                     //   }
                   // });
                  //}
                  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                } catch(err) {
                  console.error(err);
                }
              })
              console.log(resultDos);
            });
            var fs = require('fs');
            try {
                fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)
            }catch(e){

            }
    } catch (e) {
        res.json({error_code:1, err_desc:"Corrupted excel file"});
    }
  });
});
```

This is the JSON file:

Only this one is sent -->{"nombre":"Wilson Junior Toribio","cedula":"4022589632","direccion":"Calle 7 #33 Buenos Aires"},

{"nombre":"Jose Luis Toribio","cedula":"4023495023","direccion":"Calle 11 # 69 Buenos Aires"},

{"nombre":"Joel de Jesus Toribio","cedula":"4023548902","direccion":"Calle 1 # 3 Buenos Aires"},

{"nombre":"Corazon Roa","cedula":"4026984452","direccion":"Calle 3 # 19 Buenos Aires"}

I even output each document to verify if the documents are being store in the variable, this is the output:

[image: Outpu]

Comment: Did you get any error in the console?

Comment: No, it did not show any error.

Comment: Can you stringify it and print?

Comment: I stringify the documento variable, I got this error: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got {"nombre":"Wilson Junior Toribio","cedula":"4022589632","direccion":"Calle 7 #33 Buenos Aires"}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solve, I had to edit the callback to be synchronous using async and await and also use let to declare the variable cantidad inside the for:

```
let resultDos = fs.readFile("./outPutJSON/output.json", 'utf8', -> async (err, fileContents) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err)
                  return;
                }
                try {
                  let data = JSON.parse(fileContents)
                  console.log(data.length);

                  console.log(data);
                //   model.create(data, function (err) {
                //       if(err){
                //           console.log(err);
                //       }
                //   });

                  for(let cantidad = 0; cantidad < data.length; cantidad++){
                    var documento = data[cantidad];
                    var mod = new model(documento);
                    console.log(documento);
                 -> await mod.save(documento);
                    // model.create(documento).save();
                  }
```